# Count function with time condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a database similar to the following. I'm looking to count the appointed, emergency and surveyor job types that occured in working hours. Also counting the No Access and Follow On Event Summary.

The criteria is that the jobs we are looking for are ArrivedDAY NOT IN ('Saturday','Sunday) and if its a monday to friday job that the ArrTime is betweeen 08:00:00 - 16:30:00

I've managed to get the count part down but excluding the data i don't need is proving to be difficult, a point in the right direction would be appreciated.

This is on the SQL Server Studio

Cheers
Matt [image: ExampleDataSet]

Comment: Please do not use image, instead use the table structure with sample data to get quick help!!!

Comment: Post the query you used to get the result set that's in your picture (as a text code block, not as a picture). It sounds like you just need a `WHERE` clause, but all anyone can do is guess without seeing your code.

Comment: The results set is just an example of what i'd like to retrieve from the query, i've not been able to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
  Operative,
  SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 'APPOINTED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Appointed,
  SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 'EMERGENCY' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Emergency,
  SUM(CASE WHEN JobType = 'SURVEYOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Surveyor,
  COUNT(JobNumber) AS TotalJobs,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EventSummary = 'No Access' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NoAccess,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EventSummary = 'Follow On' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FollowOn
FROM
  Tbl
WHERE
  ArrivedDAY <> 'Saturday'
  AND ArrivedDAY <> 'Sunday'
  AND ArrTime >= '08:00:00'
  AND ArrTime <= '16:30:00'
GROUP BY
  Operative;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go, with a bit of guesswork as to your structure.
You could then pivot the results to get the job type as column names

```
select
 operative
,jobtype
,count(*) as [count]

from jobs --replace with your table name

where arrivedday not in ('Saturday','Sunday') --alternatively use where weekday(arriveddate) not in (1,7)

and datepart(hour,arrtime) > 8
and (datepart(hour,arrtime) < 17 and datepart(minute,artime) <= 30)

group by
 operative
,jobtype
```